# How to create a table with custom column names?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Using ClosedXML I want to create an Excel file, that contains an Excel table. I tried with

```
List<string[]> rows = new();
rows.Add(new string[] { "Id", "Title" }); // this is the header
rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "Hello world" });
rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "Hello world again" });

using var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet();
ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(rows);
wb.SaveAs("myfile.xlsx");
```

but this does not know/recognize the first row as column names, so it ends up with
[image]

So, how can I fix this? Of course I can split the header (first item in `rows`) and the remaining data, but I still don't know how to tell ClosedXML the column names to be used for the table?

Comment: You are ADDING rows.  First Row already exists.  One solution is to delete the first row.

Comment: Not sure what the downvoting is for. There's code to reproduce the issue and a clear description of the issue as well what the expected outcome is. +1 from me

Comment: @Xerillio I can understand the downvote as [Inserting Tables](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables) in the ClosedXML docs shows how to create tables with automatic headers from lists, queries and DataTables. The question doesn't even try to set A1, B1. Why isn't a `List<Message>` used here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems `InsertTable` relies on type information if you want your table to have named headers rather than anonymous string arrays:

```cs
record Item(string Id, string Title);

List<Item> rows = new();
rows.Add(new Item("1", "Hello world"));
rows.Add(new Item("2", "Hello world again"));

using var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet();
ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(rows);
wb.SaveAs("myfile.xlsx");
```

See the [related section in the documentation](https://docs.closedxml.io/en/latest/features/tables.html#table-creation).

Comment: thanks for your upvote and reply. I should have mentoined my data is dynamic (that's why I use a List of strings and not a list of some specific type). I solved it by writing the first row manually and then using insertData for the rest of the data (as of writing this: just using insertData should be sufficient), then creating a range over my rows and columns and use `CreateTable` on the range. In that case the first row is automatically used as header.

Comment: @stefan.at.kotlin Good to hear you found a solution. It sounds like something that could be useful for others, so if you have an example, I'd suggest posting it as an aswer to your own question.